# SQLITE UPDATE alternative

Tags: sqlite

I have 2 tables and like to update one of them with the values from the other.

```
software
--------
id ,
purchprice

softwarecost
------------
id ,
purchprice
```

I've tried these queries but, SQLite doesn't support JOINS with UPDATE.anybody out there who can come up with  a query for this.thanks for your help.

```
UPDATE software INNER JOIN softwarecost on software.id=softwarecost.id SET software.purchprice=softwarecost.purchprice
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want what we call a *correlated update*:

```
update software
set purchprice = (select purchprice from softwarecost where id = software.id);
```

But beware that this will set `purchprice` to `null` for each row in `software` where no matching row can be found in `softwarecost`.